# Navigation bar shows white space

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

Its a strange behaviour observed on the navigation bar a white spaced added.
How to removed it whitespace from the navigation bar.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad]
    [self loadUI];
}

-(void)loadUI {

    /// set attributes for Navigation Bar
    [[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:NO];

    self.navigationItem.title = @"Welcome"; // Title of Navigation Bar
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(243/255.0) green:(178/255.0) blue:(128/255.0) alpha:1];
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor whiteColor]};
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Removed the Image from shadow Image and back Image from the navigation Item from storyboard Navigation Controller.